# Jquery result from sum of array incorrect

Tags: jquery

```
var answ = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#result").click(function() {
answ = [];
$('input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function(){

answ.push($(this).val());  //push values in array
});
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < answ.length; i++) {
total += answ[i] << 0;
}
console.log(total);
});
});

$("#shlong").click(function() {
console.log(answ);
});


 FB.ui(
 {
  method: 'feed',
  name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
  link: 'http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
  picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
  caption: total,
  description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for                     applications to interface with users.',  
   message: 'Facebook Dialogs are easy!'
   },

 <input type="radio"  name="quiz1" value="1">
 <input type="radio"  name="quiz2" value="4">
 <input type="radio"  name="quiz3" value="1">
 <button id="result">penis</button>
 <input type="button" onclick="share_prompt()" value="Share" />
```

Hello all, I am trying to have the results from the code at the top ($total) to display in the fb.ui however it displays the entire array like: ["1"], ["4"], ["1"] how do i make it output like it is console.log which is just single number

Comment: What about the checkboxes? Post your html too please..

Comment: What is expected result of `<< 0` ?

Comment: to add the array together total being the result

Comment: I don't think you know what that really does.. It's a bitwise operator called left-shift, or something like that.. It's like multipling the number on the left by 2^n, being n the number on the right. In your case, `n=0` so it like multipling by 1. In other words, casting to `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of debbuging your messy *un-indented* code, I'm gonna offer you a simpler approach. First, the question I asked myself and couldn't find a good answer..

#### Why are you storing every value in an array??

Ok, it's out of my system now.. Let's avoid *using* that useless array of yours and get the things done quickly..

My suggestion is to add each value to the `total` while you loop..
Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#result").click(function () {
        var total = 0;

        $('input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function () {
            total += this.value << 0;
        });

        alert(total);
    });
});
```

**Edit:** in order to have a best answer, here is a [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jormaechea/dcvye15e/)

Comment: Sorry I am such a dummy, I really should look up the basics i guess again

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to declare your 'total' variable as a global variable. Add the following line to the top of your code:

```
var total = 0;
```

Comment: I don't think its that as the ui picks it up it just displays it as an array for some reason